# Addressing newly created dynamic element id's

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

and a script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').load('/something/sub_something');
});
```

on the same page. `something/sub_something` loads fine when the page does, and:

```
document.getElementById("[dynamic_id_1]_folder_link").onclick = function(){
  div_refresh();
}
```

Then `div_refresh();` refreshes `<div id="div1"></div>`. Now, any javascript functions that call on any newly created dynamic id's in the now refreshed `<div id="div1"></div>` do not work. I'm guessing it's because jquery is not aware of the new id's that have been created since the div was updated since they are dynamically generated. How can I get it to address the new id's and run the same:

```
document.getElementById("[dynamic_id_1]_folder_link").onclick = function(){
  div_refresh();
}
```

code on it?

Comment: why are you using getElementById instead of $ after creating the divs? Also, show us how you are inserting the new divs inside #div1

Answer (score 1):

With delegated event handlers. Replace the current event handler with :

```
$('#div1').on('click', '[dynamic_id_1]_folder_link', div_refresh);
```

and it will work for future elements as well.

**EDIT:**

you can not call a function with parameters that way, you'll have to do :

```
$('#div1').on('click', '[dynamic_id_1]_folder_link', function() {
    div_refresh(param);
});
```

Comment: Using this line exactly: `$('#div1').on('click', '[dynamic_id_1]_folder_link'%>', div_refresh('a_string_variable'));` it seems to run all of the functions on page load. Lets say there were 4 dynamic links created on the page load and I just substitute an alert like this: `alert("Hello World");` for the code in the `div_refresh` function. "Hello World" will display 4 times on the page load and then not again if i click on any of the links.

Comment: @JasonBurgett - yes it does. Notice that div_refresh is missing the parenthesis, and the second you add those, the function is executed immediately instead, so to add parameters to the function you need an anonymous function as well.

Answer (score 0):

try using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when binding `#div1` to an event